# Assigning value labels in Stata

Tags: stata

I could define a variable in Stata but when using the command of assigning values to it. It showed that the variable does not exist. Can you please tell me what to do further?

[image: 1]

Comment: I now noticed that some of your values are 0-3 in order of agreement and some are 3-0. While that can be technically possible to work with, it is a recipe for errors in the analysis. While it is not an answer to your original question, I strongly suggest you standardize your variables to have the same order.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error message visible. But you have defined value label sets with names `rses_sc_7_` and `rses_sc_7a_` and attempted to assign to variable `rses_sc_7` the value label set in `rses_sc_7_`.

There are at least two scenarios. In  principle there are many more, as you have shown no evidence of precisely what variables you have.

I first assume that variable name abbreviation is allowed, which is the default.

1. You have no variable `rses_sc_7` but you do have variables
   `rses_sc_7_` and `rses_sc_7a_` in which case Stata doesn't know which is to be considered the variable you are referring to.

If variable name abbreviation is not allowed, then the error is simply

2. You have no variable `rses_sc_7`

By the way, it would be a lot easier to define any distinct set of value labels just once, and then assign them to several variables. There is no need for a set of value labels to have the same name as *any* of the variables with which it is linked and a set of value labels can be assigned to several variables at once.

If this doesn't illuminate the question, show the results of

```
describe rses_sc_7*
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nick's possible causes for the error, I also want to point out that your code will throw an error already on the first line. `# Labelling Variables:` will cause the error: `Unknown #command`. Seems like you meant for this to be a comment but you used Python styles comment syntax.

Stata comments follow one of the following three syntaxes ([see usage guide here](https://worldbank.github.io/dime-data-handbook/coding.html#commenting-code)):

- `*`
- `//`
- `/*  */`

Additionally, one way to trouble shoot your code is to simplify it. There is no need to duplicate identical labels. You can create that label once and apply to all variables that use that exact label. After fixing the `#` comment syntax, simplify your code based on the example below and then follow Nick's instructions in case the source for the error becomes clear when simplifying.

```
clear 
set obs 100

* Create two categorical variables with integer values 0 - 4
gen likert1 = floor(runiform() * 4)
gen likert2 = floor(runiform() * 4)

* Display the two variables without labels
tab likert1 likert2

* Define value label once
label define likert_scale 0 "Strongly Agree" 1 "Agree" 2 "Disagree" 3 "Strongly Disagree"

* Apply value label to multiple variables
label values likert1 likert2 likert_scale

* Display the two variables with labels
tab likert1 likert2
```

Comment: This is right, naturally. My guess is that the first line is an edit for Stack Overflow, and the OP forgot or guessed wrong about Stata comments. Had that been the real code, the error message would have been quite different, as you say.